# How to convert CURLOPT_FILE for Google AppEngine?

Tags: php, file, google-app-engine, curl

Since on Google AppEngine CURL and file writing are not allowed I need help to convert the following CURL request so it can be run on it:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/external.php");
$fp = fopen("internal.php", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

fclose($fp);
header("Location:internal.php");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write the file to google cloud storage. So something like

```
$in = "http://example.com/external.php";
$out = "gs://bucket/internal.php";

file_put_contents($out, file_get_contents($in));
```

Comment: Thanks. It work perfectly on write file. However I am getting stack again on running file from the bucket for public reading. Do I need to set public access as described in [Providing Public Access to Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access)?

Comment: You know this is a really bad idea, right? Anyway, you need to use the google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets ini setting to allow a php file to be exec'd from GCS. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini

Comment: I have set php.ini with this setting: google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "my-app-id-appspot.com". Still got "Access Denied".

Comment: I found the problems it was due to my browser. I have cleared all the cache and it work now. Allow me to send you not app id (but Project Number which is 445072651661). And here is the page that being solved: [RisingBacklinks](http://www.tophyips.info/risingbacklinks/index.html). Again, thank you Stuart for your advise.